# How can I ensureDeferred a coroutine which awaits asyncio.wait(...)?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, twisted, web3py

Consider the following pair of coroutines:

```
import asyncio
from twisted.internet.defer import ensureDeferred

async def _something_that_does_io():
    return b"A stream or buffer of some sort"

async def public_interface():
    await asyncio.wait(_something_that_does_io)
    return "metadata and connection details"

d = ensureDeferred(public_interface())
```

The `ensureDeferred` here, when evaluating the function, causes `builtins.RuntimeError: no running event loop` to be raised.

The real-world application in my case is trying to ensure a deferred from `protocol.WebSocketCommonProtocol.recv` in the `websockets` library.

The `web3` library uses `websockets` for connecting to a provider, and I'm trying to make a simple mechanism to add and handle backpressure.

Adding something like `reactor.callInThread(asyncio_event_loop.run_forever)` doesn't help, because apparently it is thread-specific or something.

What's actually happening here?  How can I `ensureDeferred` such a coroutine?

Comment: Have you tried `Deferred.fromFuture(asyncio.ensure_future(public_interface()))`? What twisted's reactor is running? It should be the [asyncioreactor](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.html).

Comment: There's something sketchy happening with `asyncio.wait()`. If you replace that with `await _something_that_does_io()`, there's no error. https://pastebin.com/eL3w7b96

Comment: BTW hendrix rocks!

Comment: Also worth noting that there are deprecation notes in the docs on using coroutines with `asyncio.wait`.